# Setting up a copy of a site with IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7

I have a site running on IIS with a dyndns.org domain that points to the IP of the Windows 2008 machine hosting it. I need a copy of that site for development purposes. I set up another folder with all the files, and create a new site in IIS. I don't really have a domain for it, so I was just going to use the IP address. When I go to localhost, 127.0.0.1, or the internal IP, I get bad hostname. If I use the IP address on port 80 (the same as the real version of the site), I get 404 not found. If I use a different port so I don't have them both on the same IP with the same port, I get connection timed out. How do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting "400 - Bad request" when using localhost, Internal IP, 127.0.0.1 because you have configured the site on some other IP Address. You cannot have two Web sites running on same port (port 80 in your case), unless you use host headers. If you are planning to access the Web site on a different port make sure you have the necessary port open.

Comment: What are host headers, and how would I use them to get this to work?

Comment: check this out http://dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Add-host-header-to-a-Web-Site-in-IIS-7-IIS-75.aspx